# Как реализовать самостоятельное перемещение игрока, двигающегося вместе с движущейся платформой? Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Проблема вот в чём: мне нужна управляемая платформа зайдя на которую игрок сможет перемещаться вместе с ней, НО!, он должен быть способен ходить по ней во время движения.

Пытался реализовать вот этим кодом:

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) 
    {
         if (collision.tag == "Compartment")
         {
             this.transform.parent = collision.transform;
         }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
         if (collision.tag == "Compartment")
         {
              this.transform.parent = null;
         }
    }
```

Движение платформы:

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + 1 * 
        Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
    }
```

Но при заходе на платформу игрок хоть и перемещается вместе с ней, но абсолютно теряет возможность перемещаться по ней самостоятельно, "зависая" в одной точке. Как будет умнее сделать? (игра с точкой обзора как в первой гта)
Мои знания на уровне ниже чайника, прошу объяснять доступнее

[image: Изображения для справки! Иллюстрации проблемы не содержит]
Изображения для справки! Иллюстрации проблемы не содержит

Comment: Прошу прощения за Unity3d в метках, почему-то вопрос наотрез отказывается ставить нужную метку

Comment: юнити3д это название движка. Юнити2д не существует. Все так и должно быть

Comment: Ты не показал код движения персонажа. Если там движение реализовано через изменение `transform.position` попробуй вместо этого менять `transform.localPosition` - это позиция относительно родителя, в твоём случае - платформы.

Comment: Вообще я пытался реализовать его движение через физику (velocity)

Answer (score -1):

Если движение реализовано через физику (то есть с использованием RigitBody) то двигая платформу ты наверняка получишь движение персонажа вместе с ней. Как минимум потому, что персонаж будет "падать" на платформу из-за силы притяжения и под действием этой силы оставаться на ее поверхности.

Как реализовать движение персонажа на 3д примерах я писал здесь: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/186752)

на 2д подход уверен будет максимально близким к описаному в тойтеме.

Comment: Нет, к сожалению это не так. В 2D объект падает в нижнюю часть экрана, поэтому в играх такого типа как у меня её отключают

Comment: ВОЗМОЖНО, есть вариант как-то повернуть камеру, но это слишком сложно для осознания с точки зрения моего опыта

Comment: Уверен все еще что это не так. А делать платформу родительской это какой-то костыль потому что, внезапно, в прыжке движение будет привязано к самой платформе даже если прыжок был сделан просто вертикально - персонаж будет двигаться вместе с платформой в сторону. Это буквально кричит о том что это какой-то костыль с ютуб-видосиков. Так же будут периодически создаваться какие-то баги с отвязкой от платформы-парента. Где ты уже соскочил с платформы и двигаешься по земле, но при этом движешься вместе с ней дальше то влево то вправо))) Но как знаешь) Хочешь бороться с ветряными мельницами - борись)

Comment: Тебе достаточно посмотреть первое попавшееся видео чтобы понять как работает гравитация в 2D 0_о.
А объект родительским делаю чтобы ориентироваться на его координаты. Да, будут баги, но вопрос не в том что будет, а как сделать. Над багами думать буду уже сам

Comment: в том-то и дело что я прекрасно знаю какое качество у первого попавшегося видео в интернете) Достаточно посмотреть и первое попавшийся видео по движению для 3д что бы подчерпнуть из него информации которая убьет тебе недели а то и месяцы работы вместо того что бы разобраться как это должно работать на самом деле)))

Comment: Попытаюсь ответить без агрессии, может и правда Я чего-то не понял. ТЫ понимаешь что персонаж падает по оси Y? Это значит что падает он в сторону нижней рамки твоего монитора, а не куда-то вниз по оси Z. А платформа моя, по твоей схеме, именно так и должна ловить персонажа. Я же скрин прикреплял как выглядит моя игровая сцена

Comment: и в чем конкретно проблема изменить размер коллайдера по вертикали и добиться бега по середине платформы через все ту же физику?

Comment: Игра не бегает только по одной оси, если так сделать то персонаж не сможет, например, перебежать из левого нижнего угла в правый верхний. (передвижение как в первой гта)

Comment: Сходу ответить не могу, нужно экспериментировать чего сейчас делать не буду. Но точно могу сказать что делать парентом платформу это какой-то костыль который создаст тебе кучу проблем в будущем. Ищи информацию по разработке top-down  игр в интернете и желательно через физику. И ищи информацию на английском языке. Пока что это все чем могу помочь

Comment: ну хорошо, спасибо