# движение unity 2d обьекта в рандомное направление

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

нужно чтобы обьект в unity при загрузке сцены начинал двигатся в рандомное направление даже помогите пожалуйста как так можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Держи несколько примеров.
1 - Движение к цели с векторами. Есть еще метод [Translate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html)

```
void Update()
{
    // Move our position a step closer to the target.
    var step =  speed * Time.deltaTime; // calculate distance to move
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);

    // Check if the position of the cube and sphere are approximately equal.
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) < 0.001f)
    {
        // Swap the position of the cylinder.
        target.position *= -1.0f;
    }
}
```

2 - Через физику, наиболее верный вариант на мой взгляд. [Почему через физику лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0?ysclid=lfib04ue3j205705295). Так же есть свойство [velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html).

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
    {
        //Apply a force to this Rigidbody in direction of this GameObjects up axis
        m_Rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * m_Thrust);
    }
}
```

Остается написать метод для рандомизации вектора. Например, самое простое:

```
private Vector3 RandomizeVector()
{
   Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(minPosition.x, maxPosition.x), 
   Random.Range(minPosition.y, maxPosition.y), 
   Random.Range(minPosition.z, maxPosition.z) );
    
   return randomPosition;
}
```

И запускать все это рандомное дело в [Start()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) или [Awake()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) и двигать соответственно в [Update()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html), с физикой в [FixedUpdate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)