# Действие по нажатию по кнопке

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
void Rush()
    {
        transform.localPosition += transform.forward * speed * time.deltaTime;
    }
```

Я не понимаю, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии один раз на кнопку `GetKeyDown()`

Действия производились несколько раз.

Цикл `while` я не могу сделать, потому что это находится в методе `Update()`.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {
            timeleft -= Time.deltaTime;
            Rush();
        }

        if(timeleft <= 0 & haveCollision == false )
        {
            Stan();
        }
    }
```

Нужно, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку `Mouse 0`, действие `Rush()` выполнялось 2 секунды, или пока нет столкновения с объектом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например использовать `GetKey`

```
if (!haveCollision && timeleft >= Time.deltaTime && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1))
{
    timeleft -= Time.deltaTime;
    Rush();
}
```

Можно ещё через корутины сделать.

А вообще почитайте это: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567), вам ранее уже предлагал  взглянуть, но что-то пошло не так и вы продолжаете использовать телепортацию вместо того чтобы использовать движок для расчета перемещения.

Comment: для перемещения на ВАСД я делаю все правильно
а как зделать ривок в сторону там не написано 
и я не хочу использовать RigidBody для своего персонажа мне єто не нужно

Comment: @StasDIDUS Я же вам показал, как, и код написал, и ссылку привёл.