# Неправильное движение игрока в Unity по горизонтали

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Игрок не движется по горизонтали. Точнее, движется, но беспорядочно. У меня тут пока только управление по вертикали, то есть 3 позиции. Центр (0), верх (3.15) и вниз (-3.15). Я пытался сделать так, чтобы объект автоматически без нажатия на каких-либо клавиш двигался на право с определенной скоростью, не мешая вертикальному управлению, но он как-то очень быстро двигается вперед и возвращается в исходное положение.  Может знаете, в чем проблема?

```cs
private Vector2 targetPos;
public float Increment;
public float speed;
public float maxHeight;
public float minHeight;

private void Update()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) && transform.position.y < maxHeight)
    {

        targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + Increment);
    }
    else if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)) && transform.position.y > minHeight)
    {

        targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - Increment);
    }
}
```

Это в Unity:

```
(Increment = 3.15,
speed = 40 (скорость движение по вертикали),
maxHeight = 3.15,
minHeight -3.15. )
```

Comment: возможно будет полезным: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0

Answer (score 0):

например убрать `private Vector2 targetPos;` в `Update()`

`transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards` выполнять ПОСЛЕ проверки на нажатия кнопок.

также MoveTowards будет вызываться **каждый** кадр. И соответственно перемещать персонажа на неверную позицию. Рекомендую проверять было ли вообще хоть какое нажатие и только потом двигать