# Как предотвратить "прилипание" Rigidbody к коллайдеру объектов в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Если прыгнуть на стену и продолжать кнопку движения - персонаж прилипает к стене и не соскальзывает. Пробовал играться с гравитацией, но не привело ни к чему адекватному. [image: Персонаж на картинке прилипает к стене]

Как можно решить эту проблему, чтобы персонаж всегда подвергался притяжению?

```
[SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 7f;
[SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 14f;


private float movX = 0f;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent <Animator>();
    sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    capcoll = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>();
}


// Update is called once per frame
private void FixedUpdate()
{

    movX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float movY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(movX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

    if (isGrounded() && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }


 }
```

Comment: нужен капсуль коллайдер и правильная реализация передвижения персонажа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/186752

Comment: @AndrewStop_RU_war_in_UA я сделал капсульный коллайдер и прочёл статью. Движение, реализованное мною вроде не противоречит статье. реализовано физически с применением сил. Капсуль коллайдер ничего не поменял толком.

Comment: Я не вижу ни кода передвижения в вопросе ни капсуль коллайдера на скриншоте. Как конкретно люди хотя бы в теории могут тебе помочь если предоставляется некотектная и не полная информация в вопросе?

Comment: @AndrewStop_RU_war_in_UA извиняюсь, да. добавил код

Comment: @AndrewStop_RU_war_in_UA я поставил капсюль коллайдер только после твоего совета. Я также попробовал AddForce, использовал информацию из данной тобой статьи. Это решило проблему с прилипанием, но появилась другая. Персонаж бесконечно ускорялся пока я жал кнопку. Есть способ как-то урегулировать это?

Answer (score 0):

у тебя здесь потенциально 2 проблемы:

1. у тебя постоянная скорость толкающая на ступеньку с постоянной силой. Вполне возможно что использование `AddForce` частично поправит ситуацию.
2. А самый корень проблемы в том как ты добываешь `isGrounded`. Если бы ты прочел статью полностью на которую я сослался [ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/186752](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/186752) то ты бы увидел тамошнюю реализацию `isGrounded` более хорошего порядка

Здесь ты дотрагиваешся к ступеньке которая является и полом одновременно поэтому флаг `isGrounded()` срабатывает и изменение велосити применяется.

Если бы ты проверял `isGrounded()` только под персонажем (как было показано внутри статьи ближе к концу) - у тебя бы не зашло внутрь ифа и прыжок бы не сработал повторно и персонаж бы упал.

PS: и все равно по скриншоту не видно что у тебя капсуль коллайдер

PS2: То есть проблема все равно в том что описано в той статье и ты не применил всю информацию там поданую на практике. Перечитай статью заново.

PS3: И то есть проблема в том месте которое ты не запостил в вопросе :) Акуратнее создавай вопросы)

Comment: Я сильно сомневаюсь, что остальная часть имеет влияние на проблему. Мой IsGrounded это рейкаст под коллайдером. Он вообще никак не соприкасается со стеной

Comment: То что ты упираешься в стену и не двигаешся -- явный знак того что оно заходит внутрь ифа. А это значит что в любом случае у тебя IsGrounded срабатывает не тогда когда нужно. При даной реализации на 100% понятно что рейкаст сильно длинный и ты IsGrounded даже на такой высоте. Так что моего ответа это никак не меняет - проблема в IsGrounded и тебе необходимо перечитать статью.