# Почему анимация блокирует перемещение объекта через скрипт?

Tags: unity3d

Есть код, приведенный ниже и так же анимация, она просто на старте двигает объект повыше, сам же скрипт, движет объект когда двигается курсор. И получается, что из-за того, что на старте запустилась анимация на 1 секунду, весь скрипт не работает. Есть может какая нибудь настройка для этого?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
void Update()
{
    float movementX = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * amount;
    float movementY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * amount;
    movementX = Mathf.Clamp(movementX, -maxAmount, maxAmount);
    movementY = Mathf.Clamp(movementY, -maxAmount, maxAmount);

    Vector3 finalPosition = new Vector3(movementX, movementY, 0);
    transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localPosition, finalPosition + initialPosition, Time.deltaTime * smoothAmount);
}
```

---

Нужно анимировать парент объект, который должен двигатся и все

Comment: А как анимация реализована? Это ведь она скрипту мешает, а не наоборот. И вот это читали, не помогло? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0

Comment: Анимация это буквально запись движения 3д объекта, который должен двигать скрипт. В начале движется секунду с одной позиции на другую и все, больше не затрагивается. Что же до статьи, то там немного другое, не то что мне надо написано. Возможно есть кнопка какая-то, которая разрешает двигать объект во время анимации, или ещё что нибудь, а то вообше без понятия

Comment: @CrazyElf Оно даже не дает передвигать объект через окно сцены

Comment: Ну ещё раз. Анимация - это тоже какой-то код? Где он, как вы его вызываете? Любой код, который делает движение не "порционно" во время апдейта, а просто в цикле, будет "морозить" `GUI`, если я что-то в чём-то понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

В компоненте `Animator` поставь галочку напротив `Apply Root Motion`