# При быстром нажатии на мышку начинается непрерывная стрельба Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда я начинаю нажимать на левую кнопку мыши очень быстро, а потом резко перестаю нажимать, то у персонажа зацикливается стрельба. Он просто стреляет сам по себе, пока я не нажму ещё раз на левую кнопку мыши.

Сразу говорю, с мышкой всё хорошо, она не сломана.

Вот пример проверки на нажатие:

```
    private void Update()
{

        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && speedShoot <= 0)
        {
            if (ShootPr)
            {
                animator.SetBool("Sh", true);
                Shooting(hit);

                speedShoot = speedShootCopi;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            speedShoot -= Time.deltaTime;
            animator.SetBool("Sh", false);
        }

            AnimatorPlayer();
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0)