# Unity 2d Застревает игрок при движение

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создаю 2d игру платформер. Игрока во время движения не пропускает в какую либо сторону, что-то типо невидимой стенки становиться, при прыжке вообще чаще так застревает. Я строил платформы через TileMap, использовал для персонажа BoxCollider возможно что из-за этого баги? Также установил на Collider материал No Friction

```
    public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _speed;
    [SerializeField] private float _jumpingPower;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D _rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask _groundLayer;

    private bool _isFacingRight = true;
    private float _horizontal;
    private Animator _animator;
    private Collider2D _collider;

    private void Start()
    {
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        _collider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        _horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        _animator.SetFloat("HorizontalMove", Mathf.Abs(_horizontal));

        Flip();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        _rb.velocity = new Vector2(_horizontal * _speed, _rb.velocity.y);

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            _rb.velocity = new Vector2(_rb.velocity.x, _jumpingPower);
        }

        if(Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            _rb.velocity = new Vector2(_rb.velocity.x, _rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
        }
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        Vector2 size = _collider.bounds.size;
        return Physics2D.OverlapBox(_groundCheck.position, size, 0f, _groundLayer);
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        if (_isFacingRight && _horizontal < 0f || !_isFacingRight && _horizontal > 0f) 
        { 
            _isFacingRight = !_isFacingRight;
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            localScale.x *= -1;
            transform.localScale = localScale;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это прочитали? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0/936027

Comment: Читал, там практически не написано про мою проблему

Comment: `transform` - это откуда вообще, кто это, это же должно быть свойство какого-то объекта? И что-то я не очень понимаю, что будет если `localScale` по какой-то оси сделать отрицательной :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему, добавил компонент CompositeCollider. CompositeCollider автоматически добавит компонент RigidBody2D. Установил для RigidBody2D значение static.В TileMapCollider2D установите флажок «Used By Composite». Вся проблема была что TileMap устанавливал на каждый блок свой коллайдер из-за этого мой игрок сталкивался с ним, после всех этих настроек все коллайдеры становятся одним целым.

> Если что вот ссылка на ролик
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJik78bWSg0&t=139s