# Физический лифт Unity 3D дергается при движении

Tags: c#, unity3d

Написал простенький скрипт для лифта. Все работает хорошо за исключением подергивания то ли объектов(лифта или игрока), то ли камеры при движении игрока вместе с лифтом. Пробовал разные значения полей Interpolete и Collision Detection. Это сглаживает углы, но проблему не решает. Скрипт камеры работает в FixedUpdate так же как и передвижение персонажа.

Скрипт Elevator висит на объекте лифт на сцене:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Elevator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] AnimationCurve moovementCurve;
    [SerializeField] protected float duration;
    [SerializeField] protected float height;
    [SerializeField] protected bool AtDownPosition = true;

    private float startHeight;

    private void Awake()
    {
        startHeight = transform.position.y;
    }
    private IEnumerator PlayAnimationUp()
    {
        float expiredTime = 0f;
        float progress = 0f;

        while (progress < 1)
        {
            expiredTime += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            progress = expiredTime / duration;

            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, startHeight + moovementCurve.Evaluate(progress) * height, transform.position.z);

            yield return null;
        }
        AtDownPosition = false;
    }
    private IEnumerator PlayAnimationDown()
    {
        float expiredTime = duration;
        float progress = 1f;

        while (progress > 0)
        {
            expiredTime -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            progress = expiredTime / duration;

            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, startHeight + moovementCurve.Evaluate(progress) * height, transform.position.z);

            yield return null;
        }
        AtDownPosition = true;
    }
    public void ActivateElevator()
    {
        if(AtDownPosition)
            StartCoroutine(PlayAnimationUp());
        else
            StartCoroutine(PlayAnimationDown());
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.GetComponent<HeroController>())
        {
            other.transform.parent = transform;
            ActivateElevator();
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        other.transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

Скрипт, отвечающий за передвижение игрока

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HeroController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Oсновные параметры
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce;
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float maxSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float rotationSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float ExplosionJumpHeight;
    [SerializeField] private float velocityToExplode;
    [SerializeField] private int explosionDamage;
    private bool canExplode = false;
    private float damageJumpForce;

    //Elements for buff system
    Dictionary<string, MyDelegate> buffableStats;
    private delegate IEnumerator MyDelegate(float newRadius, float buffCooldown);


    //Ссылки на компоненты
    [SerializeField] private GameObject LoseScreen;
    [SerializeField] private Transform cameraRoot;
    [SerializeField] private SurfaceSlider surfaceSlider;
    [SerializeField] private VerticalAccelerator verticalAccelerator;
    private HealthControll healthControll;
    private MobileController mController;
    private Animator ch_animator;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private Explosion explosion;

    //Переменные для хранения временных данных
    private float defaultMoveSpeed;
    private float defaultMaxSpeed;

    public bool IsGrounded { get; private set; }
    private Vector3 moveVector// направление  передвижения
    {
        get
        {
            var horizontal = mController.Horizontal();
            var vertical = mController.Vertical();

            return new Vector3(horizontal, 0.0f, vertical);
        }
    }
//.......//
    private void Start()
    {
        healthControll = GetComponent<HealthControll>();
        explosion = GetComponent<Explosion>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        /*ch_animator = GetComponent<Animator>();*/
        mController = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Joystick").GetComponent<MobileController>();

        defaultMoveSpeed = moveSpeed;
        defaultMaxSpeed = maxSpeed;
        damageJumpForce = jumpForce;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        SetCanExplode();
        Move();
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        //вращение персонажа
        if (moveVector.magnitude > 0.1f)
        {
            float rotationAngle = Mathf.Atan2(moveVector.x,moveVector.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cameraRoot.eulerAngles.y;
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f,rotationAngle,0f);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, rotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        //перемещение персонажа

        // с инерцией
        maxSpeed = defaultMaxSpeed * moveVector.magnitude;
        Vector3 directionAlongSurface = surfaceSlider.Project(transform.forward);

        float currentVelocityXY = (Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x) + Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.z));
        if (currentVelocityXY < maxSpeed)
        {
            Vector3 direction = IsGrounded ? directionAlongSurface : transform.forward;
            rb.AddForce(direction * moveVector.magnitude * moveSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);//метод передвижения 
        }
    }
//.......//
}
```

Подозреваю, что проблема в  том, что напрямую изменяю положение лифта через transform.position.
Пробовал через Rigidbody.MovePosition, но движение тогда происходит неправильно(лифт не доходит до нужной точки и его тоже трясет):

```
            Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, startHeight + moovementCurve.Evaluate(progress) * height, 0);
            rigidbody.MovePosition(offset);
```

Если знаете как переписать предыдущий блок кода, буду благодарен.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это первым делом читали? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0

Comment: @CrazyElf, да читал. По этому туториалу у меня и реализовано передвижение персонажа(оно физическое). Для анимации движения лифта я использую animation curve. Поэтому я и спрашиваю, можно ли как-то переписать мой скрипт для того, чтобы он работал с физическими объектами, такими как мой персонаж? Или нужно переделывать все с нуля для моей ситуации?

Comment: Возможно, проблема в камере. Как вы обновляете ее позицию? Я так понимаю, она (камера) следует за игроком? Если позиция камеры обновляется в Update() - то подергивание это норма. С движением камер следует работать после того, как кадр просчитан - в LateUpdate().

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, как я и  описал выше, камера следует за персонажем и обновляется в fixed update. Я где-то слышал, что это может быть решением проблемы: разместить передвижение камеры таким же образом, как и физическое передвижение персонажа (то есть в fixed update). Но ваш совет про late update тоже попробую применить, спасибо

Comment: FixedUpdate это не место для работы с камерами! Если где-то говорят иначе - пригодность такого источника информации под вопросом.

Comment: FixedUpdate это обновление физики, естественно она не попадает в такт обновления кадров.

Answer (score 1):

Да, действительно проблема была в камере. Сменил метод обновления на LateUpdate и проблема решилась.

Comment: Приложили бы всё-таки код. Выдержку с самой сутью изменения.

Comment: '
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(
            playerTransform.position.x + posOffset.x, 
            playerTransform.position.y + posOffset.y, 
            playerTransform.position.z + posOffset.z);

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * positionLerpRate);
    }
'

Мой скрипт был достаточно прост, нужно было лишь заменить метод Update на LateUpdate.