# Персонаж не прыгает и анимация прыжка вследствии тоже не работает, даже при падении в Юнити2Д

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю игру в жанре скроллер, на практику, и остановилась на проблеме с прыжком персонажа, анимация прыжка имеется, прыжок вроде тоже расписан в коде, пробовала пользоваться чатомГПТ, смотрела видосы по решению этой проблемы, но ничего не помогло, не могли бы помочь?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerScript2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float HorizontalMove = 0f;
    private bool FacingRight = true;

    [Header("Player Movement Settings")]
    [Range(0, 10f)] public float speed = 1f;
    [Range(0, 15f)] public float jumpForce = 8f;

    [Header("Player Animtaion Settings")]
    public Animator animator;

    [Space]
    [Header("Ground Checker Settings")]
    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Проверяем, касается ли персонаж земли.
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(
            new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.1f),
            0.2f,
            groundLayer);

        if (isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Jump();
        }

        HorizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * speed;

        animator.SetFloat("HorizontalMove", Mathf.Abs(HorizontalMove));

        if (isGrounded == false)
        {
            animator.SetBool("Jumping", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("Jumping", false);
        }

        if (HorizontalMove < 0 && FacingRight)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if (HorizontalMove > 0 && !FacingRight)
        {
            Flip();
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        Vector2 targetVelocity = new Vector2(HorizontalMove * 10f, rb.velocity.y);
        rb.velocity = targetVelocity;
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        FacingRight = !FacingRight;

        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```

Comment: возможный [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0)