# Input.GetKeyDown вызывается каждый кадр

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня есть код, который при нажатии LeftControl забирает у игрока управление, и пока кнопка зажата двигает игрока вперёд по направлению в которое он смотрел изначально (механика слайда из Ultrakill)
но объект принимает вращение игрока каждый кадр, а не при нажатии, вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dash : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool GoFor;
    public GameObject go;
    
    void Start()
    {
        go = Instantiate(new GameObject(), transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            GoFor = true;
            this.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().playerCanMove = false;
            go.transform.rotation = this.transform.rotation;
            print("Click");
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
           GoFor = false;
            this.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().playerCanMove = true;
        }
        if (GoFor) 
        {
            transform.Translate(go.transform.forward * 11 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Однако, "Click" в консоль выводится только 1 раз - в момент нажатия и объект который создаётся НЕ является дочерним игроку

Comment: `new GameObject()` так делать нельзя. `Instantiate` надо выполнять из префаба. Вероятно объект находится в невалидном состоянии. Далее, вы устанавливаете объекту постоянное вращение. Если хотите импульс передать на вращение, то надо делать через [физику](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html), а не через `transform`. `Input.GetKeyDown` здесь не при чем, вы же сами сказали, что в консоль вывод производится однократно. Здесь нет никакой магии.

Comment: я пробовал не создавать новый объект а убрать строку с его созданием и указать на его место пустышку, но оно всё-равно  работает неверно

Comment: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0)

Comment: Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа - это конечно круто, но оно бесполезно в ситуации когда метод работает каждый кадр, как бы я не пытался исправить это                                            (пробовал передвижение с помощью Rigidbody, всё та-же проблема)