Персонаж "липнет" на стенам. Unity C#
К сожалению, я не могу вставить видео, но постараюсь описать.
Игру я делаю на Unity, ну в общем посмотрите на фото:

На этой картинке я зажал А, и персонаж приклеился к стене, хотя должен соскользнуть.
Что делать?
Фото коллайдеров Лягушки:

У блоков использую обычный BoxCollider2D, у Лягушки PoligonCollider2D.
Код на движение:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float JumpForce;
    private float MoveInput;

    private bool facingRight = true;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private bool isGrounded;
    public Transform feetPos;
    public float CheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MoveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(MoveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        if (facingRight == false && MoveInput > 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if (facingRight == true && MoveInput < 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feetPos.position, CheckRadius, whatIsGround);

        if (isGrounded == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * JumpForce;
        }
    }
    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }

}


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Сначала прочитайте вот это, обычно помогает: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0 Если не поможет - пишите тут. Но нужны детали - какие у вас коллайдеры, как вы обрабатываете движения, столкновения и т.д.

@CrazyElf Как отредактировать сообщение на данном форуме? Я прикреплю фото коллайдеров и код

Ну вроде должна быть какая-то кнопка. Вот ссылка по идее на редактирование этого поста: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1598371/edit Но всё-таки сначала прочитайте ответ по ссылке выше, когда сделаете всё как там написано, тогда дальше имеет смысл смотреть. Слишком много всего может неправильно быть сделано.

@CrazyElf А, ну да, я использую transform.position

Мне кажется у вас персонаж верхним углом коллайдера цепляется за платформу )  Поэтому обычно делают прямоугольные коллайдеры, а не прям точно по форме персонажа )  Чтобы соскользнуть вниз ему нужно сдвинуться чуть вправо, а вы ему не даёте этого сделать. Или даже и движок такого не позволяет, это нужно столкновение самому обрабатывать, мне кажется. Короче, попробуйте попроще коллайдер для начала. Если зелёная линия это коллайдер, я не очень разбираюсь.

@CrazyElf Не, не в этом дело, решил проверить, сейчас поставил BoxCollider2D, тоже самое, буду скрипт переписывать

@CrazyElf, ссылку на редактирование сообщения, под которым оставляется комментарий, можно передать, написав в комментарии [edit]. такая строка будет преобразована в ссылку: [edit].

@CrazyElf я придумал, я просто добавлю механику прыжков от стены

Создай Physics Material 2D и убери в нём трение, то есть в поле Friction введи 0, потом в компоненте Rigidbody 2D у лягушки в поле Material перетяни материал который ты только что создал, готово! Персонаж больше не должен липнуть к стенам

Спасибо проверю

А типо если это помогло, как на форуме показать что этот ответ помог?
