Персонаж не двигается в Unity 3d
в юнити и шарпе совсем новичок, пытаюсь написать скрипт движения по туторам с ютуба. но ни один код ещё не сработал/не сработал нормально. этот код смог заставить персонажа тронуться с места, только вот он либо падает и катится, либо не падает и стоит неподвижно(когда ставлю фризы на вращение в rb)
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class ri : MonoBehaviour

{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public float jumpForce = 30f;

    private bool isGrounded;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Movement();
    }

    private void Movement()
    {
        Vector3 moveInput = new Vector3(x:Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), y:0, z:Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        rb.AddForce(moveInput*moveSpeed);
    }


    
}


Это читали? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0

прикол в том, что я использовала уже код оттуда и ничего не работало

При перемещении игрока рекомендую использовать MovePositio();
rb.MovePosition(moveInput*moveSpeed*Time.fixedDeltaTime);


Не знаю, у меня последняя версия Unity с C# соответственно, просто f убрал, а так, была очень медленная скорость:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class ri : MonoBehaviour

{
    public float moveSpeed = 5; //убрал f
    public float jumpForce = 30; //убрал f

    private bool isGrounded;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Movement();
    }

    private void Movement()
    {
        Vector3 moveInput = new Vector3(x:Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), y:0, z:Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        rb.AddForce(moveInput*moveSpeed);
    }


    
}


По идее разницы не должно быть. f - это float, значения от этого не должны никак поменяться, тип этих переменных всё-равно float.
