Unyty Сделать так что бы при стрельбе персонаж отбрасывался
Всем привет надо сделать так что бы при стрельбе персонажа отбрасывало на "n" расстояние и как только приземлялся или задевал какой либо объект сразу останавливался без инерции.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Это читали, там может есть что-то, что поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0

Самое просто что можно сделать,это при стрельбе задавать нужный по силе и направлению velocity,а при столкновении с чем либо сразу ставить его на 0,на пример:
public void Shoot()
{
rv.AddForce(new vector2(1,-2);
}
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
 {
rv.velocity = new Vector2(0,0);
 }
пример приведен для 2д игры
