почему скорость передвижения меняется в зависимости от FPS в Unity?
Почему в 2д проекте на Unity скорость передвижения меняется в зависимости от FPS. Хотя я и  использую Time.deltaTime ?

Чем меньше FPS тем больше скорость
private void Update()
       {
           float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
           float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");


           rb.velocity = new Vector2(h , v ) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
       }




Потому что конкретно здесь использовать deltaTime НЕ надо

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567

@andreymal, ну, супер... Теперь, объясните ещё почему и как правильно. Заодно можете и ответ на вопрос дать

Физика симулируется сама по себе с своими интервалами времени, не по кадрам. Rigidbody это компонент физического движка, а velocity это свойство не дельты расстояния между кадрами, а именно значение скорости units per second. Ты перепутал тёплое с мягким. Об этом можно прочитать в документации, и примеры посмотреть, как правильно.
